# Xcode 10.2.1 Interface builder - Unable to move(drag) UI elements on View Controller (or Document Outline)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, interface-builder

I have a strange issue in my Xcode project **"Main" storyboard ONLY**. The issue is that I am unable to move any UI elements (UIView or label or a button - any UI element) on the view controller or in the document outline.

I have few more storyboards in the same project and I am able to move the elements.

I checked through similar questions on StackOverflow and found some help like -

1. Check if the **Document** **Lock** is ***Nothing***
   It's already selected as ***Nothing*** for any of the View Controllers in the Main Storyboard
2. Select a ViewController and go to Editor -> Arrange
   All **options in here are greyed out**.

Here is the link to what I am experiencing - https://recordit.co/0xNleSAYAn

Could someone help me figure out what can be done to fix this problem?

Comment: I think its bug in xcode some time i also face this issue.

Comment: @channu what do you do to solve this issue when you face it?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Wasted hours on this issue, until I restarted Xcode and it started working automatically!

Solution - Restart your Xcode!!

Answer (score -1):

If nothing else works, try the following:

1. Restart your Xcode
2. Restart your Mac